# Finding the Biur HaGra on Aggadatah Online

Tags: jewish-books, internet

I'm making a source sheet and I want to use the Biur HaGra on aggadata as a source. Any ideas where I could find it?

Answer (score 3):

An OCR version of that sefer is [available on HebrewBooks](https://hebrewbooks.org/14226).